# Flutter with firebase trying to access the current user on a different screen or widget than my login screen

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

So I have a dart file for my login screen and then a different home file. I'm trying to access the user id in the home file to get the users unique Cloud Firestore document. However whenever I call getUser() it says Future is not a subtype of type 'String'. Does that mean that for some reason the Future isn't being unwrapped to return the uid String?

```
getUser() async {
      FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
      return user.uid;
  }
```

Here is where I call get user in a different dart file than the authentication but in the same file as my getUser() function.

```
return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
     stream: Firestore.instance.collection('watchlists').document(getUser()).snapshots(),
     builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot){
       if (snapshot.hasError) {
         return new Center(
           child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
         );
       }
       if (!snapshot.hasData) {
         return new Center(
           child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
         );
       }
       else {
         var documents = snapshot.data.data;
         var vals = documents.values;
         List<WatchListItem> watchListItems = [];
         for (int x = 0; x < vals.length; x++) {
           watchListItems.add(
             WatchListItem(
               symbol: vals.elementAt(x).toString(),
               price: 190.79,
             ),
           );
         }

         return new Center(
           child: ListView(
             children: watchListItems,
           ),
         );
       }
     },
   );
```

When I try getUser().toString() the error I get is that the getter 'values' was called on null (I am trying to get database values). Can the current user only be accessed at the time of authentication? Or can it be accessed anywhere in the app at any time as long as a user is logged in? A workaround I see is to get the uid at login and then pass it as a parameter to every new Widget I go to. I'm having a really tough time with this because somehow Google barely has any documentation on using their own Flutter with their Firebase.

Comment: Where are u calling getuser

Comment: @PeterHaddad I just edited to add that information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getUser()` returns a `Future<String>` while `document()` accepts a `String` as an argument:

```
/// so that the resulting list will be chronologically-sorted.
  DocumentReference document([String path]) =>
      DocumentReference._(_delegate.document(path), firestore);
```

Therefore the best place to call `getUser()` is inside `initState`. Inside `initState` you can do:

```
String userId = await getUser();
```

Then use the `userId` in `document()`

Comment: So it still is getting null data. For some reason it just can't find the current user I suppose

Comment: After this line `FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser();` do print(user)

Comment: Also the error is here `var vals = documents.values` use connectionstate to see if data is retrieved or no

Comment: Future<Dynamic> is not a subtype of type string, so I added print(user.toString()) and now I don't see anything printed under the run area of the console. Also, initState can't be async so I had to take await out of the String userId = await getUser(); line

Comment: https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-firebase-authentication-in-flutter-50e8b81cb29f

Comment: @swiftthrow check how I get the user in initState, do the same thing in ur code

Comment: How can I start a chat with you? I'd like to ask if you know anything about Cloud Firestore and Flutter.

Comment: Check this https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-cloud-firestore-in-flutter-9ea80593ca40

Comment: You're a lifesaver! Last thing, do you know anything about a flutter bug where the on screen keyboard doesn't pop up? Sometimes I click a textbox and the on screen keyboard doesn't come and I have to restart my Android phone. I'm currently downloading Gboard to see if it's an Android or Flutter issue.

Comment: No clue, if it is a bug open it in github issue for the flutter repo